React Native FastImage not Loading Properly on 5G Network
I'm having an issue with image loading in my React Native app using react-native-fast-image. My images are loading very slowly, even on a 5G network, especially when I try to load new images multiple times. I’ve implemented preloading, but it doesn’t seem to improve the situation.
React-Native version:0.70.0
react-native-fast-image:^8.6.3
Please check below link for issue :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mKdqXXIAQXRnVbfrO_g2Tifp8bE3ma2x/view?usp=drive_link
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Dimensions, Image, ImageStyle, StyleProp } from "react-native";
import Assets from "../constants/Assets";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
import ShimmerImage from "./ShimmerImage";
import ImageZoom from "react-native-image-pan-zoom";

interface Props {
  imgStyle: StyleProp<ImageStyle> | undefined;
  uri: string | null;
  thumbnailUrl: string | null;
  isZoomable?: boolean;
}

const ImageSlider = ({ imgStyle, uri, thumbnailUrl, isZoomable }: Props) => {
  let checkImageURL = uri
    ? {
        uri: uri,
        headers: { Authorization: "someAuthToken" },
        priority: FastImage.priority.high,
      }
    : Assets.placeholder;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (uri) {
      FastImage.preload([{ uri }]); // Preload the image when URI changes
    }
  }, [uri]);

  
  return (
    <FastImage
      style={[imgStyle]}
      source={checkImageURL}
      resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
      fallback={true}
    />
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;


I want to solve this issue as below link
Please check this for expected result:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15wliQx2wo9LEaCJUOxiX-DSbWnBiIjru/view
